# Accessing Token Introspection end points in a PKCE Web Server Flow

Tags: oauth2

When using PKCE flow, I generate a code verifier and code challenge pair - appending the latter to the authorization request and the former to any subsequent calls to the token endpoint.

But what about other endpoints? The introspection endpoints require authentication by standard - but all Web Server Flow examples I saw show a "client secret" authentication...

example, from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oidc_token_introspection_endpoint.htm&type=5):

```
POST /services/oauth2/introspect HTTP/1.1
Host: https://mycompany.my.salesforce.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

token=00DR00000009GVP!ARQAQE5XuPV7J4GoOu3wvLZjZI_TxoBpeZpRb6d8AVdII6cz
_BY_uu1PKxGeAjkSvO0LpWoL_qfbQWKlXoz1f2ICNiy.6Ndr&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNI
NVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82HnFVVX19KY1uA5mu0QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCs
cA9GE&client_secret=1955279925675241571&token_type_hint=access_token
```

Accessing the introspection endpoint without authentication or with the same code verifier used for the token endpoint yields an "unauthorized" response. Any idea how to authenticate?

thanks

Comment: Can you add a POSTMAN or HTTP snippet of what you are referring to for the other endpoints

Answer (score 1):

PKCE is an enhancement that only applies to authorization code grant (aka Web Server flow in Salesforce). From [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636):

> OAuth 2.0 public clients utilizing the Authorization Code Grant are
> susceptible to the authorization code interception attack.  This
> specification describes the attack as well as a technique to mitigate
> against the threat through the use of Proof Key for Code Exchange
> (PKCE, pronounced "pixy").

The introspection request is an entirely different animal, it's covered in [RFC 7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662). PKCE isn't currently supported by the introspection spec but a similar mechanism is being contemplated down the road. From the RFC:

> Appendix A.  Use with Proof-of-Possession Tokens
>
> With bearer tokens such as those defined by OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token
> Usage [RFC6750], the protected resource will have in its possession
> the entire secret portion of the token for submission to the
> introspection service.  However, for proof-of-possession style tokens,
> the protected resource will have only a token identifier used during
> the request, along with the cryptographic signature on the request.
> To validate the signature on the request, the protected resource could
> be able to submit the token identifier to the authorization server's
> introspection endpoint to obtain the necessary key information needed
> for that token.  The details of this usage are outside the scope of
> this specification and will be defined in an extension to this
> specification in concert with the definition of proof-of-possession
> tokens.

Comment: Thank you, i concur there's no solution currently.